# reverse a string in c error subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

im trying to reverse a string but im running into a problem where it says "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" pointing to char holder = input[i]; can someone help explain that to me

```
myreverse(input, rev, len)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j= len -1;
  char string[len];

  while(i<j)
  {
      char holder = input[i];
      string[i]= string[j];
      string[j] = holder;
      i++;
      j--;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <word to reverse>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  char* input = argv[1];
  int len = strlen(input);
  char rev[len + 1]; // Adding one for the null terminator
  myreverse(input, rev, len);
  printf("Rev string is %s\n", rev);
}
```

Comment: Don't use K&R (pre-standard) C function declarations.  You omitted the types in the `myreverse()` function, so the return type and the argument types are all assumed to be `int`, and you can't subscript `int`.  It should be `void myreverse(char *input, char *rev, int len)` or thereabouts.  You don't use the `rev` parameter in the code; that's bad too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Bonus: Trying to use implicit `int` in combination with VLAs (`char string[len]`), which are a C99 feature.

Comment: @melpomene, why is it a "bonus"? Both are perfectly legal. If you're looking to blame something, blame C for accepting input this lax.

Comment: @melpomene: Oh, yeah!  Wow!  If ever there was a case for using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definitions ...`, this is it.

Comment: @zneak Not together. C99 added VLAs, but removed implicit `int` from the language.

Comment: I believe that [the point stands](https://ideone.com/0vFDmW) that if there's someone to blame, it's not the new developer trying to figure out 45 years of baggage.

Comment: fix like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wBfJgzkn8DHEetUM)

Comment: @melpomene: GCC supports VLAs as an extension in its default mode which is based on C90.

Comment: 'nor vector' - you are compiling this with a C compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter types default to `int` in C, so you need to specify them explicitly for your function since they're char pointers:

```
void myreverse(const char* input, char* rev, int len)
```

Also, your function should write its result in `rev`, not in its local variable `string`.

Comment: do u mean change the string[i] to rev[i]?

Comment: @EricVuu: You have more work to do than that.  You don't need `string` at all.  You do need to copy every character in `input` to the relevant position in `rev`.  You need to make sure the string in `rev` is null terminated.  That's all pretty easy: 
`static void myreverse(const char *input, char *rev, int len)
{
    int j = len - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        rev[i] = input[j--];
    rev[len] = '\0';
}`

Answer (score 1):

You code is almost fine.  But myreverse() doesn't do anything useful, since it reverses a local (uninitialized) string.  Probably an oversight on your part.

I don't really agree with the way you allocate the reversed string in main. Using strdup(), then freeing the memory would be better, and more portable. But if your compiler allows it...

Why don't you reverse the string in place ?

You should consider this:

```
void myreverse(char* s)
{
  int j;
  int i = 0;
  if (s == NULL)
      return;

  j = strlen(s) - 1;
  while(i < j)
  {
      char t = s[i];
      s[i]= s[j];
      s[j] = t;
      i++;
      j--;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find a bit more up to date C book first. This function definitions are from the K&R era. Here you have the reverse string function. You do need to provide size, as all C strings are zero terminated

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char tmp;
    int len;

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        {
            tmp = *(str + i);
            *(str + i) = *(str + len - i - 1);
            *(str + len - i - 1) = tmp;

        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

---

Or a different version

```
char *reversendup(consr char *srcstr, char *rev, size_t bufsize)
{
    int len;
    char *wrk;

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(str);
        if ((wrk = calloc(sizeof(char), len + 1)) != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                *(wrk + i) = *(srcstr + len - i - 1);
            }
            strncpy(rev, wrk, bufsize);
            free(wrk);
        }
    }
    return rev;
}
```

Comment: Why the extra work buffer when one is already available in `rev` ?

Comment: The OP had the right algorithm for reversing a string in place.  I mean, I fail to see how allocating a buffer when it's not needed can make things simpler and clearer.